# Как добавить возможность масштабирования в многоугольнике API?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты

Сделал Яндекс API, возникла необходимость добавить возможность увеличения масштаба карты при нажатии внутри многоугольника (как будто его нет). Подскажите, что нужно добавить? Скрипт пока выглядит так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () 
        {
        var map = new YMaps.Map(document.getElementById("YMapsID"));
        map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(60.20,62.47), 3);
        var polygon = new YMaps.Polygon([ new YMaps.GeoPoint(97.84,50.62),
                    ...
        new YMaps.GeoPoint(97.84,50.62)],
            {
                style: "polygon#Example",
                hasHint: 0,
                hasBalloon: 0
            });
        map.addOverlay(polygon);
        var style = new YMaps.Style();
        style.polygonStyle = new YMaps.PolygonStyle();
        style.polygonStyle.fill = 1;
        style.polygonStyle.outline = 1;
        style.polygonStyle.strokeWidth = 10;
        style.polygonStyle.strokeColor = "ffff0088";
        style.polygonStyle.fillColor = "ff000055";
        polygon.name = "name";
        polygon.description = "description"; 
        polygon.setStyle(style);
        YMaps.Styles.add("polygon#Example", style); 
        }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
polygon.events.add('click',function(_map){return function(){_map.setZoom(_map.getZoom()+1)}}(map));
```

[читать](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/dg/concepts/events.xml)

Comment: Я к сожалению не силен в скриптах.
Подскажите, куда этот код вставить, чтобы зум работал? Вставляю после строки "Maps.Styles.add("polygon#Example", style); ", зума нет, если вставить раньше, то все, что ниже этого кода игнорируется.